# Failed to start PostgreSQL database server

Tags: linux, permissions, postgresql

After some attempts to change permissions to access `pqsql` and `data` in `/var/lib/pgsql/data/` my postgres-server failed.

Postgresql status is:

```
 Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; 
 vendor preset: disabled)
 Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Ср 2020-02-05 12:46:48 MSK; 
 2min 19s ago
 Process: 572 ExecStart=/usr/bin/pg_ctl start -D ${PGDATA} -s -o -p 
 ${PGPORT} -w -t 300 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 564 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/postgresql-check-db-dir ${PGDATA} 
 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

 plesk.iline.pro systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL database server...
 plesk.iline.pro pg_ctl[572]: FATAL:  data directory 
"/var/lib/pgsql/data" has wrong ownership
 plesk.iline.pro pg_ctl[572]: HINT:  The server must be started by the 
 user that owns the data directory.
  plesk.iline.pro pg_ctl[572]: pg_ctl: could not start server
  plesk.iline.pro pg_ctl[572]: Examine the log output.
  plesk.iline.pro systemd[1]: postgresql.service: control process 
 exited, code=exited status=1
 plesk.iline.pro systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL database 
 server.
 plesk.iline.pro systemd[1]: Unit postgresql.service entered failed 
 state.
 plesk.iline.pro systemd[1]: postgresql.service failed.
```

In `journalctl -xe` I see:

```
input_userauth_request: invalid user isp [preauth]
plesk.iline.pro sshd[17416]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
plesk.iline.pro sshd[17416]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=118.25.105.121
plesk.iline.pro dreamwhiteApi[4034]: 2020/02/05 12:15:02 Requesting: GET  https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/entity/employee/?
plesk.iline.pro postfix/postdrop[1048]: warning: mail_queue_enter: create file maildrop/663461.1048: Permission denied
 plesk.iline.pro postfix/postdrop[25484]: warning: mail_queue_enter: create file maildrop/739287.25484: Permission denied
```

I return rights to initial state:

```
drwxr-xr-x   4 postgres     postgres     4096  pgsql
drwxr-xr-x  15  polkitd     postgres     4096  data
```

But the problem remains.

Postgresql-vertion is 9.2 (I can't change this version for some reasons in my server).

Comment: It is not quite clear from `ls` output what pokitd is, as it may depend on the options you passed to `ls`. My best  guess is that it is some user name. If so
 "/var/lib/pgsql/data" needs postgres user as owner, not polkitd

Comment: Same issue here with Fedora33 and Postgres 11. NO matter what the service won't start. Followed the instructions here until RESTART right before Step 6: https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-postgresql-on-fedora/

Answer (score 2):

The postgres data folder and all contained files should be owned by user and group postgres :

```
drwx------ 19 postgres postgres 4.0K Feb  2 14:32 data
```

Fix the permissions like this, changing the owner :

```
sudo chown -R postgres:postgres /var/lib/postgres/data
```

Finally, restart the postgresql server :

```
sudo systemctl restart postgresql
```

Comment: Thanks! Its worked for me with restarting postgres-server

Comment: Did not help, still restart exits with error.